# Several ways to get a dependent entity

Tags: entity-framework-6

I've two entities, which are linked as one to many.
I want get the dependent entities by primary key of the main entity.

**Scenario 1**
I'm calling to the dependent entity and getting this by foreign key.
 *Something like* `context.dependentEntity.where(entity => entity.foreignKey == PKMainEntity)`

**Scenario 2.**
I'm calling to the main entity and getting dependency entities.
 *Something like* `context.mainEntity.find(PKMainEntity).select(x=>x.dependentEntity)`

The primary keys have indexes by default;

What scenario is faster?

Answer (score 0):

In **Scenario 1** you fetch everything you need an nothing you don't. So this is the preferred way.

In **Scenario 2** you have two database calls. It's identical to

> ```
> var entity1 = context.mainEntity.find(PKMainEntity);
> var dependents = entity1.DependentEntities;
> ```

The second call loads the dependent entities by lazy loading.

A third way is

```
context.mainEntity.Where(entity => entity.Key == PKMainEntity)
                  .SelectMany(e => e.DependentEntities)
```

This will also execute one query. It's even likely that EF will make it identical to the first query. This form may come in handy when the dependent entity doesn't have a back reference to the the main entity.

Also for many-to-many associations this is an efficient way to get the "many" entities of a root entity (for example, the categories of a product).